# Htaccess rewrite for user profile and possible conflictions

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to ask something about htaccess redirection. I know there are lots of questions about htaccess, rewrite and pretty profile urls, but I've never found real answer of my question and I hope I can find with your help.

That pretty url rules as you know would work like changing "mydomain.com/profile.php?username=myuser" to "mydomain.com/myuser".

But let's say I have a rewrite rule for my login url :  www.mydomain.com/login

That means if user try to have exact same username as "login" how could you handle that possible confliction on rewrite?

actually possible solution might be minimum character limitation like minimum 6 chars, but it's not looking elegant since you loose your option to use more than 6 chars like "/resetpassword".

Probably a "banned words" kind of array control would be a solution when user picks a username but then you need to foresee all kind of possibilities which shouldn't be used.

Many of giant websites use this rewrite methods. Particularly Facebook uses "/username" kind of rule for pages and users in the same time.

Anyway, if someone has what is the magic behind that kind of url redirection/rewrite rules please help me out on this :)

Thanks

P.S. : I know there is another solution like "/user/username" but nowadays pointing directly to the base url and shortening full url is getting more and more popular, and I just need to understand possibilities on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have a login sub directory in the root of your site that contains the relevant files for logging a user in? That way, the rewrite rules in your htaccess file only have to deal with the whole user redirect stuff.

Comment: I'm using laravel php framework, that means sub directories wouldn't be an answer (by the way it's my mistake with saying that htaccess).

but it's pretty cool approach actually. maybe I need to use as route "/user/login" instead of "/login". that makes perfect sense :) thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something called "routes". They're typically implemented by MVC frameworks like Zend Framework, CakePHP of Symfony.

What they essentially do is forwarding *every* request to some index.php which in turn figures out from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which PHP files should handle the request.

I wouldn't recommend putting rewrite rules into your .htaccess file by PHP. Instead, try getting into PHP frameworks. They do the hard lifting for you.

Personally, I use Zend Framework. But I wouldn't recommend the new version 2 to beginners. Try ZF1. It's actually pretty easy to get into.

Comment: Actually I just started to use Laravel framework which has pretty awesome features. And actually routes is now what I'm dealing with.

and I'm using filters before routes in order to check if there is a username as get uri, so if it's successful it shows profile. 

But like I said, if there is a user which has username as "login", my /login name will be ignored or other case user profile will be ignored. 

That's what makes me think about that actually